# how to find or check details of ssl options or other options in monit

Tags: linux, monit

Sorry all,

where do you think i can find / read the details of options available / allow in monit, i tried to check expired of crt file ssl certificate by using below method

```
check host site with address example.com
    start program = "/bin/true"
    stop program = "/bin/true"
    if failed
     port 443
     protocol https
     ssl options {
      verify: enable
      ca-directory: /etc/ssl/example.com/
#      ca-file: /etc/ssl/example.com/example.com.crt
      check-expiry: 30 days
    }
    then alert
```

above config output the error related with ca-directory / ca-file (tried switch between its) does it mean it not allowed / not available to put that in ssl options ?
before try above method i only use this config, its not show any error but not work as i expected as it not check the crt file i use for ssl

```
check host site with address example.com
    start program = "/bin/true"
    stop program = "/bin/true"
    if failed
     port 443
     protocol https
     ssl options {
      verify: enable
    }
    certificate valid > 30 days
    then alert
```

Aside from ssl options i also want to find out more what kind of details option monit available from the doc link https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html kinda not completed IMHO

feel free to cmiiw and many thanks

i tried with my config and read from doc links above

Answer (score 0):

My default check to include SSL-Cert check is

```
check host FooBar with address www.example.com
    if failed ping for 5 times within 10 cycle then alert
    if failed port 443 protocol https with ssl options {verify: enable}
        ssl certificate valid 5 days then alert
```

That sends out an alert if the ping fails for 5 cycles (minutes for me) in a 10-cycle-timeframe. The second if defines an alert to be sent if the cert is due in <= 5 days.

This config checks **a remote certificate** of a website. If you want to check a local cert, you cannot use `check host`, because you are not in fact checking a host...

You could:

```
check program IsMyCertCalid path "/root/monitoring/check-cert.sh"
    if status != 0 then alert
```

while `/root/monitoring/check-cert.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
certFilePath="/opt/acme.sh/certs/example.com/example.com.cer"
certValidityEnds="$(openssl x509 -noout -enddate -in "$certFilePath" | awk -F'=' '{ print $2 }')"
certValiditySeconds="$(date -d "$certValidityEnds" +"%s")"
now="$(date +'%s')"

printf "Certificate %s is valid until %s" "$certFilePath" "$certValidityEnds"

[ $now -gt $certValiditySeconds ] && exit 1

exit 0
```

Advantage is, that this also writes the validity to the program output that is visible in the web frontend. Output would be like:

```
Certificate /opt/acme.sh/certs/example.com/example.com.cer is valid until Dec  2 09:20:00 2023 GMT
```

Regarding documentation I can only recommend to read through the full document provided by tildeslash. It is very much complete, but not very well structured...

Comment: Thanks boppy - then thats mean i could check multiple live website from one monit server for sslcert validity with check host from one server monit isnt ? please cmiiw & thank you for sharing your script - i could modify and use it for my ends

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely check multiple servers, and multiple domains with one monit. Just create one `CHECK HOST` entry for every domain you want to watch. Keep in mind that if multiple domains point to the same server, it's not needed to have the ping check on every domain...